# Não estou conseguindo usar get_rect com convert/convert_alpha e subsurface

Tags: python, pygame

Eu estava fazendo assim:

```
class Esqueleto (pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__ (self):
        self.imagem = pygame.image.load("imagem/esqueleto.png")
        self.rect = self.imagem.get_rect()
        self.imagem = self.imagem.convert_alpha()
    def desenhar (self, superficie):
        superficie.blit(self.imagem.subsurface([self.coluna * self.tile_size, self.linha * self.tile_size, self.tile_size, self.tile_size]), self.rect)
```

O problema é que dessa forma a largura e a altura do rect serão as do spritesheet não a do recorte. Não consigo pensar numa forma de usando get_rect pegar as dimensões do recorte.

Answer (score 0):

Se o seu problema são só a altura e largura, simplesmente crie um retangulo com x e y = 0 e largura e altura = self._tile_size  - não precisa criar um retângulo baseado na imagem lida do disco:

```
self.rect = pygame.Rect((0, 0, self.tile_size, self.tile_size))
```

(Você no entanto não configura `self.tile_size` dentro do `__init__`. De onde vem o `tile_size`? se for uma varipavel global, o prefixo `self.` não é necessário)

Mas, indo além disso,  com esse código você não está aproveitando todo o potencial da subclasses de "sprite" do pygame: 
Se o seu `self.rect` tiver a posição desejada na tela para sua sprite, e o atributo `self.image` já contiver a subsurface desejada, o pygame pode desenhar sua sprite automaticamente quando você chamar o método `draw` de um group contendo sua imagem.

```
tile_size = 128  # exemplo

class Esqueleto (pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__ (self):
        self.sprite_sheet = pygame.image.load("imagem/esqueleto.png")
        self.rect = self.imagem.get_rect()
        self.imagem = self.imagem.convert_alpha()
    def update (self):
        self.image = self.sprite_sheet.subsurface([self.coluna * tile_size, self.linha * tile_size, tile_size, tile_size]))
        self.rect.x = ... # posicao x em que o objeto será desenhado na tela
        self.rect.y = ... # posicao y em que o objeto será desenhado na tela
    # def draw(self, superficie): 
          # não é necessário esse método:
          #  - o método "draw" do Group ja faz blit de
          # self.image na posição delimitada por self.rect
```

E para usar isso, ponha suas sprites num grupo (`pygame.sprite.Group` ou derivado),  e chame os métodos `update` e `draw` do grupo. (O primeiro chama o  `update` de cada sprite no grupo, o segundo faz o blit).

https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group